# Unable to fetch parent data in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Hi I have an issue with hibernate with  many to many relation. I have two tables having many to many so i introduced one more table which holds the relation between the two tables. In my configuration(hbm) files i have made lazy="false" and fetch="join" because i want to fetch both parent and child information whenever i query parent table.Now i want to fetch parent tables data from the third table(which holds the relation between both tables). but i am unable to fetch parents information, i am getting the below exception.

**Configuration snippet**

```
Parent 1 - 
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.sample.Technology" table="TECHNOLOGY">
            <id name="technologyId" type="big_decimal">
                <column name="TECHNOLOGY_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
                <generator class="increment" />
            </id>
            <property name="technologyName" type="string">
                <column name="TECHNOLOGY_NAME" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="technologyDesc" type="string">
                <column name="TECHNOLOGY_DESC" length="500" />
            </property>
            <set name="regionTechnologyCapabilities" table="REGION_TECHNOLOGY_CAPABILITY" cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy = "false" fetch="join">
                <key>
                    <column name="TECHNOLOGY_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" unique="true" />
                </key>
                <one-to-many class="com.sample.RegionTechnologyCapability" />
            </set>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
Parent 2 : -

<class name="com.sample.Region" table="REGION">
    <id name="regionId" type="big_decimal">
        <column name="REGION_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="regionName" type="string">
        <column name="REGION_NAME" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="regionDesc" type="string">
        <column name="REGION_DESC" length="500" />
    </property>
    <set name="regionTechnologyCapabilities" table="REGION_TECHNOLOGY_CAPABILITY" cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy = "false" fetch="join">
        <key>
            <column name="REGION_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.sample.RegionTechnologyCapability" />
    </set>
</class>

Relational Table 3 :-    <class name="com.sample.RegionTechnologyCapability" table="REGION_TECHNOLOGY_CAPABILITY">
        <id name="regionTechCapbId" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="REGION_TECH_CAPB_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="region" class="com.sample.Region" fetch="join">
            <column name="REGION_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="technology" class="com.sample.Technology" fetch="join">
            <column name="TECHNOLOGY_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
```

Comment: Will it be possible to provide the configuration file or some simplified version of the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you manually map the join table ? Use a bidirectionnal many-to-many and let Hibernate handle the join table !

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sample.Technology" table="TECHNOLOGY">
        <id name="technologyId" type="big_decimal" column="TECHNOLOGY_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <set name="regions" table="REGION_TECHNOLOGY" inverse="true">
            <key column="TECHNOLOGY_ID"/>
            <many-to-many column="REGION_ID" class="com.sample.Region"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sample.Region" table="REGION">
        <id name="regionId" type="big_decimal" column="REGION_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <set name="technologies" table="REGION_TECHNOLOGY">
            <key column="REGION_ID"/>
            <many-to-many column="TECHNOLOGY_ID" class="com.sample.Technology"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: This bidirectional M2M relationship mapping will not help my requirements because i want to add more columns specific to join table in future. If that is the case how can i do that mapping.